# Is it possible to run Knights of the Old Republic 2 at a higher resolution?

Tags: star-wars-kotor-2

I grabbed KOTOR 2 in the latest Steam sale to see what all the fuss was about with the recently completed [Sith Lords Restored Content Mod](http://www.moddb.com/mods/the-sith-lords-restored-content-mod-tslrcm).

The game runs fine, but I'm finding the max resolution of 1024x768 jarring. Is there any way I can raise this closer to my native 1440x900? If it's locked at 4:3 and has no widescreen support, that's fine, I'm perfectly happy with 1200x900, but playing the game letterboxed this badly is kind of painful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set a custom resolution by editing the ini files in the game installation folder. The specific file in question is `swkotor2.ini`, and the specific section of this ini file you're looking for is `[Graphics Options]`. If any of the following settings don't exist you can add them within this section to get the resolution you want;

> ```
> Width=1920           Horizontal resolution
> Height=1080          Vertical resolution
> FullScreen=1         Set fullscreen mode
> ```

The width and height settings in this file determine the screen resolution that Knights of the Old Republic 2 will run at, allowing you to run the game at resolutions that are not present within the KOTOR2 launcher.